# Uncaught Reference Error: prompt is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

here is my code

```
var person =prompt("Please enter your name");
console.log(person);
```

output:

> Uncaught Reference Error: prompt is not defined

I also tried

```
var person = window.prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");
console.log(person);
```

and output is:

> Uncaught Reference Error: window is not defined

Comment: NodeJS doesn't implement `prompt`. That's only in the browser.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/command-line/how-to-prompt-for-command-line-input/

Answer (score 0):

Prompt and window are defined on the client-side and won't work on the server-side. To get around this problem, I think the link below would be helpful for you.

[getting user input in nodejs](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/getting-user-input-in-node-js)